# AngularJS not processing JSON correctly

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, playframework

I have a Play framework project using AngularJS for its views. The controller responsible for querying data makes 2 requests, each returning a JSON block. The first one works correctly and it's displayed properly. The second one's data is pretty much destroyed by Angular (example below).

The JSONs are created correctly prior to being rendered, as it's shown through the application's log.
This is the correct JSON (taken from the Play Framework routed method's log):

```
{"id":5,"name":"auditoria","url":null,"version":1,"methods":[]}
```

This is how AngularJS prints it. It tokenizes :

```
[{},{"0":"a","1":"u","2":"d","3":"i","4":"t","5":"o","6":"r","7":"i","8":"a"},{},{},{"length":0}]
```

And here's the controller:

```
app.controller("ViewCtrl", [ "$scope", "$resource", "$routeParams", "apiUrl",
        function($scope, $resource, $routeParams, apiUrl) {

            var ServiceList = $resource(apiUrl + "/services");
            $scope.services = ServiceList.query(); //JSON is displayed properly

            if ($routeParams.id) {

                jsonServicoQuery = apiUrl + "/services/" + $routeParams.id
                var Service = $resource(jsonServicoQuery);
                $scope.currentService = Service.query(); //JSON is butchered
            }
        } ]);
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="bs-sidebar hidden-print" role="complementary">
            <ul class="nav bs-sidenav">
                <li><a href="/create"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></li>
                <li ng-repeat="s in services| orderBy:'name'"><a
                    href="/view/{{s.id}}">{{s.nome}}</a>     
                    <ul>
                        <li ng-repeat="m in s.methods| orderBy:'name'">{{m.name}}
                            [{{m.id}}]</li>
                    </ul></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-9" role="main">
        <div class="bs-docs-section">
            <div class="page-header">
<!-- displaying the whole currentService JSON for debugging purposes -->
            {{currentService}} 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Anybody has any clues about what am I doing wrong?

---

**Update:** Service.query() executes the method routed by Play Framework.

Route configuration:

```
GET      /api/services/:id              controllers.Services.show(id: String)
```

And `controllers.Services.show(id: String)` implementation:

```
public static Result show(String id) {
    Service s = Service.findById(id);

//JSON displayed here is correct, log below
    Logger.info("At Services show, json " + Json.toJson(s)); 

    return ok(Json.toJson(s));
}
```

Log:

```
[info] application - At Services show, json {"id":5,"name":"auditoria","url":null,"version":1,"methods":[]}
```

Comment: It looks like there is something wrong with your service.  Can you post the content of your Service.query()?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the problem, I should have used `$scope.currentService = Service.get();` instead of `$scope.currentService = Service.query();`